# Creating a map from a var in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, var

How does one create a `map` from a `var` in Clojure?

For example, if one has a `var` called 'var', as follows:

```
(def var "I am a var")
```

And then, one wants to convert it to the following:

```
{:var "I am a var"}
```

How does one achieve that?

By the way, just to be clear:
I want the `f` from `(f var)` where 'f' converts `var` to `{:var "I am a var"}`.

Comment: Do you really want a Clojure `var`?  Or are you trying to simply add a kv pair to a map?  http://swannodette.github.io/2014/12/17/whats-in-a-var/

Comment: @jmargolisvt adding a KV pair is also alright with me. But I want the key to be of the same name as the var's name.

Comment: Include an example of it's usage. It is ambiguous whether you want to create a var with a name where it's value is a map with the var name as the keyword and value of some expression (e.g. literal or s-expression). Please clarify.

Comment: @FrankC. The latter would be fine.

Comment: I updated the question to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a map from the var name to its value you can create a macro:

```
(defmacro to-map [sym]
  `{(keyword '~sym) ~sym})

(to-map var)
=> {:var "I am a var"}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the answer. I want the f from (f var) where 'f' converts var to {:var var}.

Comment: isn't it enough to to do it in a compile time, without any quoting? like this: `(defmacro to-map [sym] {(keyword sym) sym})`

Comment: @leetwinski That is a better suggestion than any of the existing answers.

Comment: This works. Although the suggestion of @leetwinski works as well. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do I do to make it usable with map as well?
(It seems to spew out wrong results)
`(map #(to-map %) [a b])`
`({:p1__68# 1} {:p1__68# 2})`

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this macro can take optional args to construct a map.

```
(defmacro to-map [& vs]
  "foo = 1, bar = 2.  (to-map foo bar) ==> {:foo 1 :bar 2}"
  `(let [ks# (map keyword '~vs)]
     (zipmap ks# [~@vs])))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do if using the var's metadata:

```
(defn process-var [param]
  {(-> param meta :name keyword)
   @param})
```

in repl:

```
user> (def x "fourty two")
#'user/x

user> (process-var #'x)
{:x "fourty two"}

user> (def y 1001)
#'user/y

user> (map (comp process-var (ns-interns *ns*)) '(x y))
({:x "fourty two"} {:y 1001})

user> (map (comp process-var (ns-interns *ns*)) '(x y process-var))
({:x "fourty two"} {:y 1001} {:process-var #function[user/process-var]})
```

also you can take a var straight from namespace's symbols table:

```
(defn by-name
  ([name-symbol] (by-name name-symbol *ns*))
  ([name-symbol ns]
   {(keyword name-symbol)
    (deref (ns-resolve ns name-symbol))}))

user> (by-name 'x)
{:x "fourty two"}

user> (by-name 'map 'clojure.core)
{:map #function[clojure.core/map]}

user> (by-name '*clojure-version* 'clojure.core)
{:*clojure-version* {:major 1, :minor 8, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}}
```